# execute javascript function after adding fields with cocoon

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, cocoon-gem

I'm developing my application in rails, in my app I'm extracting a form in a modal window through ajax, the form has a cocoon button to add nested records, the problem comes when adding new nested resources with cocoon those new fields do not respond to a javascript function that detects if the field changed the value

my application.js

```
function validateFileType(){
  $( ".file_to_upload" ).change(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
  });
}
```

part of my index.haml.erb:

```
  =link_to '<i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>'.html_safe, adjuntar_archivos_path(:id => record), :remote => true

#adjuntar_archivos
```

my method in controller

```
  def adjuntar_archivos
    @billing = Billing.find_by_id(:id)
  end
```

my adjuntar_archivos.js.erb

```
$("#adjuntar_archivos").html("<%=j render :partial => 'adjuntar_archivos'%>");

$("#addDataModelModal").modal("show"); 

validateFileType();
```

my partial _adjuntar_archivos.html.haml

```
#addDataModelModal.modal.fade{"aria-hidden" => "true", "aria-labelledby" => "exampleModalLabel", role: "dialog", tabindex: "-1"}
  .modal-lg.modal-dialog{role: "document"}
    .modal-content
      = form_for(@billing, remote: true) do |f|
        .modal-header
          %h5#addDataModelModalLabel.modal-title Archivos adjuntos
          %button.close{"aria-label" => "Close", "data-dismiss" => "modal", type: "button"}
            %span{"aria-hidden" => "true"} ×
        .modal-body
          .links
            = link_to_add_association "<i class='fa fa-plus'></i> Añadir adjunto".html_safe, f, :billing_files, partial: 'billing_file_fields',:"data-association-insertion-node" => "tbody.adjuntos",:"data-association-insertion-method" => "prepend", class:"btn btn-success btn_naranja btn", id: "link_1"

          .row
            .col-md-12
              #payment_details
                %table.tabla_personalizada#tabla_detalle_pago
                  %thead
                    %tr
                      %th Descripción

                  %tbody.adjuntos
                    = f.fields_for :billing_files do |billing_file|
                      = render 'billing_file_fields', f: billing_file


        .modal-footer
          %button.btn.btn-secondary{"data-dismiss" => "modal", type: "button"} Close
          .text-center
            = f.submit 'Guardar', :class => 'pull-right btn btn-primary'
```

my partial _billing_file_fields.html.haml

```
%tr.nested-fields.detalle_pago
  %td= f.text_field :description, class: 'form-control file_to_upload'
```

how can i make the new fields created by cocoon also run the .change method of my javascript function?

UPDATE:

I have tried to execute the function within the partial "billing_file_fields.html.haml" in the following way:

```
%tr.nested-fields.detalle_pago
  %td= f.text_field :description, class: 'form-control file_to_upload'

- content_for :javascript do
  :javascript


    validateFileType();
```

but it still doesn't work

Comment: You have to re-run the Javascript for the .change method to work. When you load the page you load the initial Javascript, When you add the new record dynamically, the page does not recognize it because it was not part of the initial load. You can try putting `validateFileType();` inside `_billing_file_fields.html.haml`

Comment: @VictorLuna I had tried it but no javascript code is executed when rendering the partial. I updated the post with the code I used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

---

```
    function validateFileType(){
        $( ".file_to_upload" ).change(function() {
            alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
        });
    }
```

---

To

---

```
    function validateFileType(){
        $(document).on('change', ".file_to_upload" ).change(function() {
            alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
        });
    }
```

---

The code will make sure that any element (even if the element is dynamically added) will have the given callback on change.

NOTE: PLEASE MAKE SURE THAT THIS FUNCTION IS CALLED ONLY ONCE SO CONSIDER CALLING THIS FUNCTION IN `index.haml.erb`.

Comment: thanks a lot,  I was getting an error with the .change, I changed it to $(document).on('change', ".file_to_upload", function() { and it works, thanks